# check if array is full

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to do check if an array is full and print out to the user he is unable to enter more books.

```
static Object[][] books=new Object[2][];
```

I am asking 3 values from the user and am storing to another array called "row".

```
 Object[]row=new Object[3];
```

After that i loop through the books array and check if it has a null value inside of it and add the "row" array with the given values of the user.
the problem am having is i cant give any feedback if books array is full after entering two rows of values.

```
boolean empty=false;
while(empty==false){
    for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
            if(books[i]==null){
                books[i]=row;               
                empty=true;
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not having a variable

```
int bookCounter = 0;
```

which you can increase/decrease everytime you add/delete books and then just check it against your max number of books (which I assume is `books.length`)

In this way you don't need to loop over the array, which is not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the `while` loop.  After the `for` loop ends, check your `empty` variable that you're already setting.  If it's `false`, then give your feedback to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are always full. Even each element is `null`. If you initialize it with the size of 10, then JVM will alocate memory and fill the all the arrays positions with default value. What is: `0` for primitives numbers and char type, `false` for primitive boolean type and `null` for Objects.

So, your code won't work with a int[] for instance. Because there won't exist any `null` element.

That's why you dont have a `count()` method... You can create a method that is named `countNotNull()`. But you'll need to interate for all the array long.

The best solution is to use a variable to count when you add/remove itens form array. As
Guillermo Merino said.