# C# Check if array is "full"

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, user-input

I've got a question  and a problem about arrays.

In the code below, the plan is to offer the user a menu and if the user choose nr 1 the program will ask the user to enter a name and age in order to fill the array. But I want the code to check if the array with names is full before the user is asked to enter the name (this is because the name is the first thing the user is asked for). If the array is "full" it should write something like "Full", if not then the user is asked to enter the information.

Here is were the problem enters the picture...

Because the menu is looped as long as the user don't wish to exit the program (via the menu), this option can be chosen several times. If the the user choose the same option again then that would mean that the array is full and that no more input can be made to the same array.
In my current code this "check" function does not work. I've tried with different solutions including if/else, bool loops and a custom designed method. They all failed.

A quick search here at stackoverflow, gave some ideas but no one worked for me, although one of the threads seemed to be good way but I did not understood exactly how to construct that kind of method. Here is the link to that answer: [check if array is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694507/check-if-array-is-full) (the interesting part is the "int bookCounter = 0;"

I'm sure there is a simple way to solve this but I would really appreciate your help with this!

Remarks: Some pieces of the code is written in Swedish but I translated all the important parts to English  .

```
 public void Run()
    {
        int choice;
        do
        {

            //Menyn:

            Console.WriteLine("Hello and welcome to this awesome buss-simulator!{0}", Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose an option in the menu below.{0}", Environment.NewLine);
            Menytexts();


            choice = CorrectEntryMenu(1, 8); //Method to make sure it's a number. Not related to this.

            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Welcome, please enter the passengers name:"); //lägg till passa.
                    string name = Console.ReadLine();

                    int age = CorrectEntry("We also need the persons age: "); //Another method for correct input. Not the problem.

                    add_passenger(age, name); //Sending input info to the method containing the arrays.

                    Console.WriteLine("The passenger is registered. " +
                        "Press any key to return to the manu");

                    Console.ReadKey();

                    break;

                case 2:
                    print_buss();
                    break;


            }
        } while (choice != 8);


    }

    //Metoder för betyget E

    public void add_passenger(int age, string name) //Method containing the arrays and the problems.
    {

        string[] passengername = new string[2]; //Array for all the names. temporarily set to 2 spaces. 



         //idealistically the method for checking the array is inserted here.

        for (int n = 0; n < passengername.Length; n++) //To fill array if not full
        {
            name = passengername[n];

            int[] passengerage = new int[2]; //Array for all the ages. Temporarily set to 2 spaces. 

            for (int x = 0; x < passengerage.Length; x++) //If the namearray is not full then age is entered.
            {
                age = passengerage[x]; 


            }

        }
```

Comment: The question/answer you linked seems reasonable.  Basically, arrays are of fixed length, so you'd maintain a variable to count how many times you've added something to your array.  When that count reaches the length of the array, it's full.  Though, if you're currently *not* maintaining a counter, how do you know which array position to write to when adding something new?

Comment: you probably need to look into static variables (outside of the methods) that can be used throughout the process. Keeping track of the counter (which place you last placed a value) would be the next thing so you can increment that and add the value. If counter == array.Count(), then stop

Comment: Since your collection can be of variable size, it should be of a type that represents that (i.e. `List<T>`) rather than an array.

Comment: Thank you guys! Although the idea of a list instead of an array would be the easiest way to go ( I guess), in this project I would prefer to use an array. For more info about the counter variables, is there any good keywords that I can use in my search?

Answer (score 1):

You've defined string[] passengername inside your add_passenger method, therefore it ceases to exist when that method returns (and the added passenger is lost).

You could start by making string[] passengername an instance variable.

Also:

```
  age = passengerage[x];
```

Should probably be:

```
  passengerage[x] = age;
```